# Distinguish 2-way and 3-way interactions in binary data, independent of reference category

Tags: categorical-data, log-linear

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb{P}}$I have three variables $X_a, X_b, X_c \in \{0, 1\}$ and I define a joint distribution:

$$
\P(X_a, X_b, X_c) \propto \exp 
\left \{ 
\theta_{abc} \mathbb{I}_{\{X_a = 0 \wedge X_b = 0 \wedge  X_c = 0\}} 
\right \}
$$

from which we get the following conditional probabilities of $X_a$

$$
\P(X_a = 1 | X_b, X_c) \propto \exp 
\left \{ 
\theta_{bc} \mathbb{I}_{\{X_b = 0 \wedge  X_c = 0\}} 
\right \}
$$

and

$$
\P(X_a = 2 | X_b, X_c) \propto 
\exp 
\left \{ 
0
\right \}.
$$

where $\theta_{bc} = 1$ and $\mathbb{I}_{\{X_b = 0 \wedge  X_c = 0\}}$ is the indicator function for the event $\{X_b = 0 \wedge  X_c = 0\}$.

So the distribution is only parameterized by a three-way interaction between the variables $\{X_a, X_b, X_c\}$. My goal is to recover this 3-way interaction with logistic regression. However, as I show in the below example, this turns our to be problematic, because depending on the choice of reference categories for the predictors $X_b$ and $X_c$, the 3-way interaction is either represented in the intercept or (as desired) in a parameter for the 3-way interaction.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
# Sample Data using Gibbs Sampling
set.seed(1)
n <- 2000; nIter <- 100
data <- matrix(NA, nrow=n, ncol=3)
theta <- 1

for(i in 1:n){ # loop cases
    burnin <- matrix(NA, nrow=nIter, ncol=3)
    burnin[1, ] <- sample(0:1, size = 3, replace = T)
  for(iter in 2:nIter) { # loop iterations

    for(p in 1:3) { # loop variables
      potentials <- rep(NA, 2)

      if(p==1) pd <- burnin[iter-1, 2:3]
      if(p==2) pd <- c(burnin[iter, 1], burnin[iter-1, 3])
      if(p==3) pd <- burnin[iter, 1:2]

      potentials[1] <- exp( all(pd==0)*theta  )
      potentials[2] <- exp( 0  )

      probs <- potentials / sum(potentials)
      burnin[iter, p] <- sample(0:1, size = 1, prob = probs)
    }
  }  
    data[i, ] <- burnin[nIter, ]
}
```

Sanity check:

```
> table(data[,1], data[,2], data[,3])
, ,  = 0

      0   1
  0 555 179
  1 210 218

, ,  = 1

      0   1
  0 204 210
  1 222 202
```

As desired, the configuration $\{0, 0, 0\}$ has a higher relative frequency than all other configurations, which have (roughly) the same relative frequency.

Now we fit a logistic regression to model

$$
\log \frac{\P(X_a = 1 | X_b, X_c)}{\P(X_a = 0 | X_b, X_c)}
$$

We do this using `glm()`, which takes the smaller category (0) as 'reference' category and hence uses the indicator function for the higher category (1) as a predictor. We get:

```
mod <- glm(data[,1] ~ data[,2] + data[,3] + data[,2]*data[,3], family = 'binomial')
cf <- coef(mod)
cf
    (Intercept)           data[, 2] 
     -0.9718606           1.1689698 
      data[, 3] data[, 2]:data[, 3] 
      1.0564180          -1.2923671
```

Now what should this model predict?

For the case $X_b = 0, X_c = 0$ it should predict $\P(X_a = 0 | X_b, X_c) > \P(X_a = 1 | X_b, X_c)$ or equivalently $$\log \frac{\P(X_a = 1 | X_b, X_c)}{\P(X_a = 0 | X_b, X_c)} < 0 \,.$$ For the three other configurations of $X_b, X_c$ the model should predict $\P(X_a = 0 | X_b, X_c) = \P(X_a = 1 | X_b, X_c)$ or equivalently $$\log \frac{\P(X_a = 1 | X_b, X_c)}{\P(X_a = 0 | X_b, X_c)} = 0\,.$$

And the model does that:

For $X_b = 0, X_c = 0$ we get:

```
Xb <- 1
Xc <- 1
cf[1] + cf[2]*(Xb == 1) + cf[3]*(Xc == 1) + cf[4]*(Xb == 1)*(Xc == 1)
-0.9718606
```

And for $X_b = 0, X_c = 1$ we get:

```
Xb <- 0
Xc <- 1
cf[1] + cf[2]*(Xb == 1) + cf[3]*(Xc == 1) + cf[4]*(Xb == 1)*(Xc == 1)
0.08455739
```

So far so good. My problem now is that I cannot identify the presence of 2-way and/or 3-way interactions of the model parameters. Basically the 3-way interaction is absorbed in the intercept, and the other parameters are chosen such that they predict smaller equal probabilities for all other configurations.

If I used the indicator function for the event 0 instead of the event 1 in the logistic regression, I would not have this problem:

```
data_rec <- abs(data - 1) # swap 0 and 1
mod2 <- glm(data_rec[,1] ~ data_rec[,2] + data_rec[,3] + data_rec[,2]*data_rec[,3], family = 'binomial')
coef(mod2)
            (Intercept)               data_rec[, 2] 
             0.03883983                 -0.12339722 
          data_rec[, 3] data_rec[, 2]:data_rec[, 3] 
            -0.23594909                  1.29236706
```

So I get one parameter capturing the 3-way interaction, and all other parameters are zero (for large $n$). Of course, if the 3-way interaction would give a higher probability for the configuration $\{1, 1, 1\}$ I have again the same problem and actually the reference category of the previous model (1) would have led to interpretable parameters.

So the problem I have is that whether I can identify the presence of 2-way or 3-way interactions depends on the dummy coding of my predictors, which is undesirable.

I guess this is a problem probably many other people already had so I am wondering whether there are any elegant solutions to this?

My final goal is to recover a model of the form of the joint distribution above with $p$ variables that can include 2-way and 3-way interactions between those variables using a series of $p$ logistic regressions.